# How to access user role and permission information?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

We need to provide access to the following:

1. A list of all users, their status roles, permissions, and basic info (user name, email, business unit, etc.)
2. A list of all permissions
3. A list of all roles
4. Relation between roles and permissions
5. Relation between users and roles
6. Relation between users and roles (this is relevant due to custom permission options that are out of the scope of the role)

We can use REST API, SOAP API, AMPScript, or SQL quarry. Or whatever is suggested.

I was only able to access the AccountUser object using SOAP API. But it doesn't have all the info I need.

For instance in case of a custom permission I get this:
Individual role for XXX
Individual role for XXX
Individual role for XXX>

Maybe some of the information can be found under PermissionSet object, but it is not retrievable.

Any idea how to gain access to the needed information?

Here are the sources I found related so far but was not enough to solve this conundrum:

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/accountuser.html
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/permissionset.html
3. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.html?fireglass_rsn=true.html#fireglass_params&tabid=ac297959fcac2f8e&application_server_address=firegtiep04.hq.corp.phoenix.co.il&popup=true&is_right_side_popup=false&start_with_session_counter=1
4. [Retrieving User Details using SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166424/retrieving-user-details-using-soap-api)
5. [Read AccountUser's assigned to BusinessUnit in Enterprise Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28753/read-accountusers-assigned-to-businessunit-in-enterprise-account)
6. [User Permission Access Report](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327347/user-permission-access-report)
7. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_enterprise_user_permissions.htm&type=5

**Edit**

Following the commenters, I have tried to retrieve **AccountUsers** from the **BusinessUnit** Object using SSJS WSProxy. But no I'm getting an error:
`The Request Property(s) AccountUsers do not match with the fields of BusinessUnit retrieve`

This corresponds to the described Object check I did, AccountUsers cannot be retrieved.

Note: This was executed using a cloud page on the top parent BU.

Retrieve code:

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

try {
    
    var soapObject = "BusinessUnit";
    var colsArr    = ["Name", "IsActive", "ParentName", "AccountUsers"];
    var res   = prox.retrieve(soapObject, colsArr);

    if (res.Status == "OK") {
        Write(Stringify(res));
    }else{
        Write("res.Status = "+ res.Status);
    }
} catch (error) {
    Write(Stringify(error));
}
```

Comment: I have documented my solution on my SFMC Dev Blog: https://charliefay.medium.com/sfmc-account-user-audit-check-roles-and-permissions-via-api-c14356be0114

Comment: @charliefay, thanks! but I'm not sure this will solve the custom permission issue (i.e checked not via a role). I have tested an API call to the same object AccountUser. when custom permission was retrieved I got this: Individual role for XXX...

Comment: ahh Yes I also get the Individual role for {accountUserId} from the Roles soap object. I will try digging for individual user permission. Also, side note, something to be aware of if you're looking into Roles object via the API: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350736/role-soap-object-is-missing-marketing-cloud-roles

Answer (score 2):

I've built something similar to what you've described.

I went through all of [@charliefay](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/75989/charliefay)'s material on this (and [thank you](https://media1.giphy.com/media/lEVZJzy4w15qE/200w.gif)).  It didn't provide the custom roles -- as you've found.

I spent more than 2 months enduring lame SF Support responses and the crappy API documentation, but I finally figured out.

Here are a few hints:

- First, *do not trust any of the documentation about what SOAP properties are available or retrievable*.  Do a DESCRIBE on each object using Postman, get *all* of the property names and do a RETRIEVE on *all* of them.  Let the actual web service endpoint tell you which ones aren't actually retrievable.  You'll be surprised at the disparity.
- The `BusinessUnit.AccountUsers` property **from the parent BU** is the most accurate source of `AccountUser` data that I found.
- Mirror the raw from the `BusinessUnit` and `AccountUser` SOAP objects into data separate extensions.
- Build an `AccountUser_Roles` data extension and fill it with Roles from `BusinessUnit[x].AccountUsers[y].Roles[z]`
- Permissions is a huge and ultimately meaningless data-set that is way to granular to try to audit or manage.  I ended up just sticking to `BusinessUnit`, `AccountUser` and `AccountUser_Roles`.
- Write a SQL Query to join and/or denormalize the data into the desired output.

Hope this gets you on the right track.

**EDIT**

Here's a sample Describe for BusinessUnit:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndpoint}}</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <DescribeRequests>
                <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
                    <ObjectType>BusinessUnit</ObjectType>
                </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
            </DescribeRequests>
        </DefinitionRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Adam. I couldn't find any template for Describe action. Can you refer me a sample one? I tried to use WSProxy to describe the `BusinessUnit` object and AccountUsers property is not retrievable. It's the same with `AccountUser` and its property BusinessUnit. I wonder how you link between these 2 soap objects?

Comment: Thanks, but won't this keep me with the same issue of assigning permission manually not via a role. I'm getting now: `<Individual role for XXX>` under the permission

Comment: @yoni349 -- I found this method will return the actual custom Role name instead of `Individual role for XXX`.

Comment: @duyduc27 even if the property value is marked as "not retrievable" try to retrieve it.  I've confirmed that you can retrieve the `AccountUsers.AccountUserID` from the `BusinessUnit` object using WSProxy.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, I'm getting an error when trying to retrieve AccountUsers `The Request Property(s) AccountUsers do not match with the fields of BusinessUnit retrieve`. I have added an edit with the code to the post. So maybe it's been updated to no retrieve now?

Comment: You don't need to specify it in the retrievable properties.

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs - I ran a WS Proxy retrieve on all the columns returned by the describe and removed the columns one by one which were included in the error response until I didnt get an error.  The response I get is: "AccountUsers": null

Comment: Here is the retrieve call I ran: https://gist.github.com/charliefay/54f00a6baedb393306eee67ada3621c8